# The image of a basis under an onto linear transformation is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having a problem with 1 question. Thank you

Suppose $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is an onto linear transformation.

If $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, show $\{T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n)\}$ is also a basis.

Honestly i dont understand this question at all...please help with it, i just dont have any idea how to approach it.

Comment: Please try typing out the questions here rather than providing links.

Comment: not sure how to type lambda or somethings in this chat...

Comment: i am first time ever on this site, i figured posting image would be easier to read...the second link works perfectly and there are no ads on it at all..

Comment: if you can give me a place where i an post images so people dont have problems ill gladly repost them...its 6 30am here now and i been at this for over 8 hours...i am stuck on this part =(

Comment: @user161045 .. You can learn to type math symbols, equations etc here : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: ok ill try to edit my post so it is easier for you guys to understand or read it...i am sorry for the hastle, just very very tired and i really really want to go to sleep its 6 33am lol now...!_! i been at this for so long i am losing track of up and down...

Comment: I have edited the Question to provide what mathematical content could be found in your image link.  Please review and edit the Question yourself to explain where you are stuck.  For example, if you are trying to do this exercise but you have not understood what a linear transformation is, that would be different from not knowing what a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ means.  Your Question still lacks context useful to helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Think it through one step at a time.

What do you have to do? Show something is a basis. How do you do that? First, you show it's linearly independent, then you show it generates the space.

Linear independence. How do you show something is linearly independent? You show that there's no non-trivial linear combination of them that equals zero. How do you show that? Algebra: you write down "linear combination equals zero", and then prove that all the coefficients are zero.

$$\lambda_1T(v_1)+\lambda_2T(v_2)+\dots+\lambda_nT(v_n)=0$$

And you need to show $\lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_n=0$. If you're stuck, look at what the assumptions of the exercise are: that $T$ is linear and onto. Obviously you'll have to use at least one of those assumptions, so that sharply limits what your next step should be.

Now you need to show that it generates the space. This requires a bit more creativity than the first question. Use the fact that in an $n$-dimensional space, any set of $n$ linearly independent vectors generates the space.

Answer (score 0):

Well for the second link that you have provided, yo may note the following :

Consider a linear combination of $T(v_1),T(v_2),\ldots, T(v_n)$ such that

$a_1T(v_1)+a_2T(v_2)+\ldots +a_nT(v_n)=0$

By linearity of $T$, this will imply that $T(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots+a_nv_n)=0$. Then use the fact that $T$ is one one ($T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is onto and so its one one also). So you will get $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots+a_nv_n=0$. Since $\lbrace v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\rbrace$ is a basis so $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_n=0$. Hence $T(v_1),T(v_2),\ldots, T(v_n)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: so you are saying that its one to one and because of that its linearly independent?

Comment: ya we have to use this property to show linear independence. I think the proof is clear, isn't it ?